# JSON schema code gen in C

Tags: java, c, json, code-generation, jsonschema

Please forgive me for the possible stupid question as I am not a C developer. I need to do research for the project. We are considering using JSON from the Java side. However, there are some projects are written in C. I need to scout to see if there's a lib in C that can code gen based on a JSON schema. That way I have better control on the C side. I have been googling but I haven't be able to find something like the jsonschema2pojo lib. Can anyone help and shed the light? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @JimGarrison I mentioned that I want to know if there's a lib in C that can code gen based on a JSON schema. Could you tell me what else do I need to provide to make it more specific to everyone?

Comment: There are lots of forums for C where this would be on-topic, just not here.

Comment: I am a java developer not a C developer. I don't know where would be suitable. If you feel this is "off topic" could you tell me where and I will move my question. Thanks

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/#l=schema can generate code for C++ if it helps, no C though

Comment: @vearutop thanks! Is it true that people don't use JSON in C?

Comment: @asun I don't think it is true, at least there is https://github.com/netmail-open/wjelement

Comment: You can use library like YAJL to create json schema. Well it’s personal choice, I m using yajl in my two projects. YAJL has lot of stuff not needed you need to check what’s your need. Other small json parser library is janson, you can have a look at that library.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer thanks! however I already have a json schema just want to make sure C follows the schema to create the json messages

Comment: @asun C follows the schema to create json message, it’s big yes.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer good to know. In that case, how can one ensure a schema is followed in C?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org).

[Here](https://github.com/opensourcerouting/c-capnproto) you can find a way to generate C code from the protocol.

You can also turn Cap'n Proto messages to and from JSON using `libcapnp-json`.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. If I only have a JSON schema will I be able to set "data model" based on the schema? I see it's for c++ lib, will it work in C? Sorry I am not that familiar with C/C++.